# How can I create transparent divs that have a picture as background on an otherwise black background?

Tags: html, css

I want to recreate an interface similar to Windows Phone 10.

You can see an example of what I try to achieve in HTML in this picture:

[image]

The middle tiles act like Windows on the baby picture while the space between tiles is black.

Comment: I see no transparency.

Comment: You can give body background color as black and create those divs putting margins around them will create the same thing.

Comment: I mean transparent as you can see the background image through them.
@satya I need to create the background image for every tile then by hand, do I get you?

I was hoping there was a way to avoid this so I can change the background dynamically

Comment: No. Your body has a background and these elements are children of the body, so they are displayed "above" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic going on here. In the picture you've supplied the phone has a desktop of a child that is letterboxed (black stripe across top and bottom). The tiles on the top and bottom of the screen are opaque and show their own backgrounds. The tiles in the middle are fully transparent, but have a solid black border to them to show the child behind them.

To make the tiles, you simply need this:

```
 .tile { background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); 
         border: 3px solid black;
  }
```

Take a look at this fiddle for a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnafvvx9/6/

Answer (score -1):

For a dynamic approach:
You could slice a picture in many litte parts (and delete the sliced borders). Then you create and align different divs with a individual background image containing your sliced picture parts.

There is also a kind of work around for static pages:
Create one div with the big (not sliced picture).
Use a transparent PNG image containing only the "border" of the black background. Place that in a div on top of the other div and you got the style. Then you need to add little divs ontop of the positions where you can see the picture.

The important thing is, that these designs require pixel perfect static layout. This means you can't scale divs size or change the position when the browser window or screen is smaller. But its also the easiest way do do that and the last suggestion allows to change the picture without slicing it.

For real dynamic approach you could load the same picture (unsliced) in every button (use different css id for everyone) and position the background of them individually to fit together. The advantage of this is, that you can then use CSS3 for instance to scale the button size on hover. This can lead to a cool expanding image effect. Just look up
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I will wait a bit if anyone comes up with some magic way, else I will follow your approach.

Comment: @Maulzal Typically, there's code in the question, too ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan touché

Comment: @Maulzal Sorry, im new to stackoverflow. I hope this will be forgiven.

Comment: @Horst23 I really appreciate your detailed answer, thanks again! And welcome from another newbie